# Pandas - Comparing two dataframes by date and find missing entires

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a Dataframe with list of unique working dates in a month, called days.

I have another Dataframe that has the list of days an employee has reported to work, called reported.

I am trying to find days when an employee did not report to work.

Given below is sample view of the Dataframes:

```
days
11/1/2018
11/2/2018
11/3/2018
11/4/2018
11/5/2018
11/6/2018
11/7/2018
```

View of the Dataframe called reported:

```
emp_id, date
1001,11/1/2018
1001,11/2/2018
1002,11/1/2018
1002,11/3/2018
1003,11/3/2018
```

Expected output (that lists down days an employee did not report):

```
emp_id,date
1001,11/3/2018
1002,11/2/2018
1003,11/1/2018
1003,11/2/2018
```

Update I created the first Dataframe as below

```
import numpy as np
df_1 = np.sort(df_master.date.unique())
df_1_df = pd.DataFrame(df_1)
df_1_df.columns

RangeIndex(start=0, stop=1, step=1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) with default inner join and then [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) by all unique values of `emp_id` and `date`, last `merge` with parameter `indicator=True` for filtering not reported rows:

```
reported['date'] = pd.to_datetime(reported['date'])

df1 = reported.set_index(['emp_id', 'date'])
mux = pd.MultiIndex.from_product(df1.index.levels, names=df1.index.names)
```

```
df3 = (df1.reindex(mux)
         .reset_index()
         .merge(reported, indicator=True, how='outer')
         .query('_merge != "both"')
         .drop('_merge', axis=1))
print (df3)
   emp_id       date
2    1001 2018-11-03
4    1002 2018-11-02
6    1003 2018-11-01
7    1003 2018-11-02
```

Another solution, thanks @IMCoins is filtering by [`isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.isin.html) with `~` for invert boolean mask:

```
df2 = df1.reindex(mux)
df3 = df2[~df2.index.isin(df1.index)].reset_index()
print (df3)

   emp_id       date
0    1001 2018-11-03
1    1002 2018-11-02
2    1003 2018-11-01
3    1003 2018-11-02
```

Comment: I built the first dataframe by extracting all unique values from a df, but it has no column. I have updated my initial post with the code, could you please assist how could I address this..

Comment: @scottmartin - I think here this DataFrame is not necessary.

Comment: Wouldn't it be more efficient to do a `df.loc[~df['date'].isin( some_DatetimeIndexes )]` ?

Comment: @IMCoins - good idea, but is necessary working with MultiIndex, added to answer.

Comment: @IMCoins - Abot performance - hard to know, it depends of many factors like length of df, number of unique values in each levels and number of lissing rows...

Comment: @scottmartin - sorry, it is from first solution `mux = pd.MultiIndex.from_product(df1.index.levels, names=df1.index.names)`

Comment: @jezrael, thanks. I encountered another error when I tried  df2 = df1.reindex(mux)


and it said "Exception: cannot handle a non-unique multi-index!".. Could you please assist. Thanks..

Comment: @scottmartin - sure, problem is duplicated values, use `df1 = reported.drop_duplicates(subset=['emp_id', 'date']).set_index(['emp_id', 'date'])`